# python principals Tic tac toe input - is a one liner possible?

Tags: python, function

The task in python principals is stated as follows:

Here's the backstory for this challenge: imagine you're writing a tic-tac-toe game, where the board looks like this:

```
1:  X | O | X
   -----------
2:    |   |  
   -----------
3:  O |   |

    A   B  C
```

The board is represented as a 2D list:

```
board = [
    ["X", "O", "X"],
    [" ", " ", " "],
    ["O", " ", " "],
]
```

Imagine if your user enters `"C1"` and you need to see if there's an X or O in that cell on the board. To do so, you need to translate from the string `"C1"` to row `0` and column `2` so that you can check `board[row][column]`.

Your task is to write a function that can translate from strings of length `2` to a tuple (row, column). Name your function `get_row_col`; it should take a single parameter which is a string of length 2 consisting of an uppercase letter and a digit.

For example, calling `get_row_col("A3")` should return the tuple `(2, 0)` because `A3` corresponds to the row at index `2` and column at index `0` in the board.

My solution:

```
def get_row_col(cor):
    cor.lower().split()
    return (int(cor[1])-1,ord(cor[0]) - 65)
```

My question is if there is a way to solve it using 1 line (excluding the def function), i.e

```
def get_row_col(cor):
    return ...
```

Comment: It already is one line, cor.lower().split() does nothing in your current implementation

Comment: remove `cor.lower().split()` it is not assigned to anything and therefore not really doing anything

Comment: Just... remove split! Your line has no effect anyway

Comment: Because it returns an answer that you're not assigning to anything. The `split()` function does not modify what it's called on, it returns a new list of strings that you have to assign to something.

Comment: The reason your code does not need that split is that `cor[0]` is already the first character in `cor`, and `cor[1]` the second. And since split is going to split your string on whitespace, that split returns a list with one element. E.g., with `"C1"` the split returns `["C1"]`.

Comment: @joanis Not to mention the result of all that is never assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain a bit your mistake.
`str` type is **immutable**. It generally means that you cannot change value of some `str`, what you do behind the scenes is creating new `str` and pointing to another place in memory. Saying that, all methods of `str` (like `lower` or `split`) creates new thing (another `str` or `list` in that case).

Such line

```
my_str.any_method()
```

never has an effect and it should be

```
my_str = my_str.method()
```

So yeah, you already have 'one liner', but if you really want to have just one line (please, never do that in real code) you could write

```
get_row_col = lambda cor: (int(cor[1])-1,ord(cor[0]) - 65)
```

Answer (score 0):

"A", "B", "C" have ASCII numbers

```
[ord(c) for c in "ABC"]
>>>[65, 66, 67]
```

same as "1", "2", "3"

```
[ord(c) for c in "123"]
>>>[49, 50, 51]
```

So just convert the chars to integer

```
def get_row_col(cor):
    return (ord(cor.upper()[0])-ord('A'), ord(cor.upper()[1])-ord('1')) 

print(get_row_col("b3"))
>>>(1,2)
```